# Trying to animate a UIView height from the bottom up, instead of the top down

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, uiview, swift3

I'm trying to animate the height of a UIView from a height of 1px to a height of 41px. It sort of works now, but instead of the view animating from the bottom to the top, it goes from the top to the bottom.

Here is the code that I am using to make it animate up and down

```
    func animateBackgroundHeightUp() {
    print("animate")
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.personBg.frame.size.height = 41
    })
}

func animateBackgroundHeightDown() {
    print("animate")
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.personBg.frame.size.height = 1
    })
}
```

I think I have to figure out how to set the origin y, but I can't seem to find a swift 3 example.

**EDIT**

```
func animateBackgroundHeightUp() { print("animate") UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { self.personBg.frame.size.height = 41 self.personBg.frame.origin.y = -41 }) } 

func animateBackgroundHeightDown() { print("animate") UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { self.personBg.frame.size.height = 1 self.personBg.frame.origin.y = 41 }) }
```

What ended up working for me is this configuration. But I'm confused as to why the origin needs to be 20?

```
   func animateBackgroundHeightUp() {
    print("animate")
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.personBg.frame.size.height = 41
        self.personBg.frame.origin.y = 20
    })
}

func animateBackgroundHeightDown() {
    print("animate")
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.personBg.frame.size.height = 1
        self.personBg.frame.origin.y = 59.9
    })
}
```

The 59.9 number was figured out by printing out the origin y's value on load.

Comment: You should avoid fractional positions, since this causes the rendering engine to interpolate, and makes the view that's at a non-integer position look blurry. (You can get away with x & y positions that end with .5 on Retina devices since there are 2 pixels per point on Retina devices.)

Answer (score 3):

The origin in iOS views is the top left corner of the screen. A view's frame pins the origin at the top left corner, and the height tells how far it extends down.

If you increase the height of a view, its top won't move - it's bottom will extend downward.

If you want a view to appear to grow upward, you'll need to increase the height while decreasing the origin.y by the same amount.